# Ramda: Delete object in nested structure

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to delete an object by given id using ramda, here is my JSON data format:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "orders",
  queries: [{
    id: 120,
    name: "test1",
    queries: [{
        id: 141,
        name: "order1"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 121,
    name: "test2",
  }, {
    id: 115,
    name: "test3",
  }, {
    id: 122,
    name: "test4",
  }, {
    id: 125,
    name: "test5",
    queries: [{
        id: 126,
        name: "order2"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 143,
    name: "test6"
  }, {
    id: 144,
    name: "test7"
    queries: [{
        id: 145,
        name: "order3"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 146,
    name: "test8"
  }]
}
```

in above example, given `id: 141`, I'd like to delete that object in the queries.

I've tried using nested map with filter, but seems not working. Anyone could give some clue?

Comment: Can you please check whether your JSON is valid one and paste the right JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is a chance that the `id` to be removed is the first node, it is probably best to wrap the top level object in an array. This will also help with a recursive solution.

First we can use [`R.reject`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reject) to filter out all elements with a matching `id` for a given list of objects. Then we can use [`R.map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) and [`R.evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) to recursively apply the same function to the list of `queries` in each object.

```
const removeId = (id, objs) => R.map(
  R.evolve({ queries: xs => removeId(id, xs) }),
  R.reject(R.propEq('id', 141), objs)
)
```

You can see an example of this using your data in the snippet included below.

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "orders",
  queries: [{
    id: 120,
    name: "test1",
    queries: [{
      id: 141,
      name: "order1"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 121,
    name: "test2",
  }, {
    id: 115,
    name: "test3",
  }, {
    id: 122,
    name: "test4",
  }, {
    id: 125,
    name: "test5",
    queries: [{
      id: 126,
      name: "order2"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 143,
    name: "test6"
  }, {
    id: 144,
    name: "test7",
    queries: [{
      id: 145,
      name: "order3"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 146,
    name: "test8"
  }]
}]

const removeId = (id, objs) => R.map(
  R.evolve({ queries: xs => removeId(id, xs) }),
  R.reject(R.propEq('id', 141), objs)
)

const result = removeId(141, data)
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```